# Ask question to reach support?

Tags: support

I have encountered a strange question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669808/access-to-api-via-partner-program-linkedin) that I immediately marked as "off-topic" as it really isn't about programming. The person asking, though, have informed me that it was supposed to be asked *this way*:

> This is the way I was told to contact them, I have already tried their support.

IMHO she is making it up, but I could be gravely mistaken - so I am reaching out for answer here - is it a standard "procedure" to ask questions regarding support?

Comment: [LinkedIn directing people to SO?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278748/839601)

Comment: It is debatable to ask questions regarding specific product. In that case it would also be debatable to discuss specific functionalities of let's say Google App Engine...but trying to reach the support regarding API access? That is just strange...